# Using a for loop to Print and Two-Dimensional Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I am trying to complete an assignment (so point in the general direction would help greatly) within which I have to  (in order):

1. Declare a 2d String Array,
2. Assign Values to the array of two people and their favourite drink
3. Output using a for loop

---

```
public class doublearray {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String Preferences [] [] = new String [2][2];
        Preferences [0][0]= "Tom, Coke";
        Preferences [1][1]= "John, Pepsi";

        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
            for (int j =0; j<3; j++){
                System.out.print(Preferences[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I receive this error message

> Tom, CokenullException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at doublearray.main(doublearray.java:15)

Now, I understand that ",Tom,Coke" have been assigned only to **ONE** [0] which is why null appears, but I've no idea how to remedy that or make it print successfully.

Any help would be most appreciated, I've been stuck on this for about an hour.
Thank ya'll.

Comment: The inner loop will allow j to be 2 which is out of the bounds of the inner array. In other words Preferences[0][2] is out of the bounds of the array because the length is 2. Inner loop should be j < 2, not 3. Or more reliably Preference[i].length.

Comment: and the answers begins......

Comment: Why is `i < 2` and `j < 3` ?

Comment: Than you guys very much, I had changed that earlier from >2 to >3 to attempt to rid myself of 'nullnull' being printed. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want something like that :

```
Preferences [0][0]="Tom";
Preferences [0][1]="Coke";
Preferences [1][0]="John";
Preferences [1][1]="Pepsi";
```

> You'll know that Preferences[0] is about Tom
>   You'll know that Preferences[1] is about John

And once you have it, the columns will be [0]=>"name" [1] =>"drink"

```
[0][1] will give you Tom[0] s drink[1] [Coke] for example.  
[0][0] will give you Tom[0] s name[0] [Tom] for example.
[1][1] will give you John[1] s drink[1] [Pepsi] for example.  
[1][0] will give you John[1] s name[0] [John] for example.
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it's the correct way to traverse a two-dimensional array of arbitrary size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Preferences.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Preferences[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(Preferences[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
  //size for inner loop was 3 but should be 2      
  for (int j =0; j<2; j++){

    System.out.print(Preferences[i][j]);}
}
 }
```

For arbitrary size

```
for (int i=0; i<Preferences.length; i++){
      for (int j =0; j<Preferences[i].length; j++){

        System.out.print(Preferences[i][j]);}
    }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

In second loop `j` should also `j<2` instead of `j<3`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j =0; j<3; j++){
```

needs to be

```
for (int j =0; j<2; j++){
```

You didn't make the array big enough for `j` to be `== 2` so it's `out of bounds`

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
 for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        for (int j =0; j<2; j++){

    System.out.print(Preferences[i][j]);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that has ridded me of the error but the return is now Tom,Cokenullnull,John Pepsi,

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your 2D array as:

```
new String [2][2];
```

and your loop seeems to be tring to fetch the elements such as

`new String [0][3];` and so on because of your inner for loop:

```
    for (int j =0; j<3; j++)
```

Leading to array index out of bound. You may need to change the inner for loop to

```
    for (int j =0; j<2; j++)
```

and try.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your second for-loop. Consider you only have space for 2 Values per final dimension

Answer (score 0):

How can you take your j from 0 to 2 since your array length is 2 and you start your loop from 0.

change  **for (int j =0; j<3; j++)**  to  **for (int j =0; j<2; j++)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (String[] row : Preferences) {
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(row) );
    }
```

Output:

[Tom, Coke, null]

[null, John, Pepsi]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is always a good idea to provide some explanation along with your answer code. People looking for a solution will more likely understand your answer.