# How do I put in individual values into an 2-dimensional array with an unknown length?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a code that will allow the user to input values for an arrays row and columns. I have finished that part, but now I am tasked with the problem of inputting a value for index 00, index 01... and so on until the user's array is filled. I am having trouble finding a solution.

Many solutions online have it so that you input values all at once, however, I need to break it up so that the user is asked index by index to enter a number. I am specifically needing to input a value at index 0 0, index 0 1... and so on. This is hard, because I don't know how many index's the user will initialize.

To clarify, I need the user to be prompted to input at each index 0 0, index 0 1... but it cannot exceed how many index's they declared.

Please help.

I have tried,

array[0][0] = input.nextInt();

seems to make it so I can input a value at index 0 0, however, how do I make this so that it will continue the length of whatever the user declared the columns and rows to be AKA the two-dimensional array.

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript?

Comment: it is java, I'm sorry I thought they were the same

Comment: Here is a hint - nested loops.

Comment: @Chaosfire I understand what nested loops are, I believe, however, how do I break it up so that the user is prompted to enter each value instead of entering all of it at once?

Comment: `array[0][0] = input.nextInt();` - don't use hardcoded values, use the variables of the loops.

Comment: @Chaosfire I'm confused, could you explain futher?

Comment: [Using a for loop to Print and Two-Dimensional Array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997361/using-a-for-loop-to-print-and-two-dimensional-array-in-java) - this should help. For your case, instead of printing the values, assign them.

Answer (score 0):

`Hi May,
Without giving you the code...
numberRows = get the number of the rows
numberCols = get the number of columns.
create array[numberRows,NumberCols]

for (int ii = 0; ii < numberRows; ii++) {
    for (int jj = 0; jj < numberCols; jj++) {
        store value location array[ii,jj] =  get value from user;
    }
}`

Comment: This makes sense! Do I have to do "ii" and "jj" or can i just put "i" or "j". Also! Where can I add in System.out.println so that I can request their index 00.. and so on. How do I program it so that It runs through the amount of indexs they have…

Comment: You can use anything you want as a variable. I use ii and jj because if you have to search through your code, the iterators are easier to find.

Comment: This will only loop to the number rows they put in and the number of columns they put in.